# Can Spock even have children?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, spock

Spock was the only Human-Vulcan half breed because he was genetically created, not born. In an interview between Gene Roddenberry and Sarek (played by Mark Lenard, of course) on the album Inside Star Trek, Sarek reveals the origins of Spock through casual conversation. He was a test-tube child, incubated outside of his mother because humans and Vulcans are naturally incompatible.

So, would Spock even be able to have children? Is it possible that Spock is actually sterile, like most species cross-breeds in biology?

Comment: we know their are tons more half blood children, and that in enterprise it was alluded that a simple drug was all that was needed for humans and vulcans to mate cross species. so while this may have been originally true what your saying, the 40 years of trek cannon has changed almost everything you said.

Comment: What episode of Enterprise?  I don't recall that, but then all I ever really watch is the 4th season.  :P

Comment: when their in the expanse they meet another enterprise that either went back in time or was stuck, anyway the captain of the ship was tpol and tuckers child, and i believe he also had children of his own on board. the doctor had made a drug that allowed them to have children. i cant remeber 100% what it was but, from what we know about tucker i doubt hed have liked having a child that grew up outside of tpol, he was very much a traditionalist and that would have very much put him off.

Comment: I'll have to consult Netflix!

Comment: it just says that plox was able to overcome the genetic differences on memory alpha and im pretty sure thats all that was said as well.

Comment: Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home was originally intended to reveal that Lieutenant Saavik was pregnant with Spock's child. This was dropped, however, supposedly at the request of Leonard Nimoy. Not an answer, but it shows which way they originally wanted the wind to blow...

Comment: also we see that other half breads can have children i believe worf's son was from a half klingon half human mother, and it appears to have been a surprise/unplanned aka no doctor was involved. so she at least was not sterile from being essentially a mule

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Saavik#Final_film_appearance - Spock knocked up Saavik.

Comment: @MightyFerengi It was brought up in ENT twice.  Once in the episode [E²](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/E²_(episode)), and in the two-parter of [Demons](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Demons_(episode)) and [Terra Prime](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Terra_Prime_(episode)) it was a plot point and made more explicit by Phloxx at the end of the second part.  And it wasn't a simple drug, it was mixing DNA with methods similar to cloning

Comment: Spock was at least sexually correct enough to be driven to Pon Farr once.

Comment: Not the same species, but K'Ehleyr was a half-Klingon half-human and she successfully had a child with Worf. B'elanna Torres was also half-Klingon and had a child with Tom Paris. Neelix mentions that he's 1/4 Mylean, implying that a half-Talaxian half-Mylean reproduced. Simon Tarses was 1/4 Romulan. Lastly Yedrin Dax was a descendant of Jadzia Dax, and there were no other Trill that could have been in his ancestry, so some Trill-something hybrids had to reproduce. In conclusion, ST clearly does allow mixed-species characters to reproduce.

Comment: in TNG "Sarek" Picard said he met Sarek before, at the wedding of Sarek's son.  Sybok died before Picard was born, so this son was either Spock or Sarek's hypothetical child by his second Human wife Perrin.  Being married is not a guarantee of being able to have children, of course.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it's absolutely possible for Spock, and any other alien hybrid, to have children. Several relevant episodes of *Enterprise* are referenced in the comments, which I want to expand on.

The episode [Future Tense](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Future_Tense_(episode)) revolves around the *Enterprise* crew discovering a ship from the future. The pilot's corpse is found inside, and Doctor Phlox determines that it was the result of many generations of inter-species breeding. In particular, it had DNA from Humans, Vulcans, and Terrellians, as well as others that Phlox couldn't identify.

A later *Enterprise* episode, [E<sup>2</sup>](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/E%C2%B2_(episode)), involves a future version of *Enterprise* run by the descendants of the original crew. The crew of this ship is about two generations removed from the main cast and the First Officer, Karyn Archer, is Captain Archer's grand-daughter. Karyn's grandmother is specifically said to be an alien, which means that Karyn's father was a half-Human who successfully reproduced.

In a more concrete example, Worf has a son by K'Ehleyr, introduced in the TNG episode [The Emissary](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Emissary_(episode)). K'Ehleyr constantly points out that she's only half-Klingon, and yet she and Worf have a child with no problems.

A similar case occurs in *Voyager*: human Tom Paris and half-Klingon B'Elanna Torres have a daughter, born in the episode [Endgame](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Endgame_(episode)).

**EDIT:** As [HorusKol](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71550/can-spock-even-have-children/71562?noredirect=1#comment147755_71562) points out in comments, the *Next Generation* episode [The Drumhead](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Drumhead_(episode)) involves Crewman Simon Tarses, who had a Romulan grandfather.

The Star Trek mythology even explains how this is possible. A late episode of *The Next Generation*, [The Chase](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Chase_(episode)) establishes that all humanoid species in the galaxy share common genetic material with a progenitor race, who specifically seeded the galaxy to create different humanoid species:

[image: A member of the humanoid Progenitor race]

Although it kind of flies in the face of known genetics, it's a good enough explanation for Star Trek.

Comment: TNG episode "The Drumhead" had a starfleet crewman who was one-quarter Romulan. I'm sure there's even more examples.

Comment: the 1 quarter romulan crewmember makes 100% sure, as romulans and vulcans are the same species only about 2000 years apart with micro-evolution not changing them enough to be different in an significant way.  (not that i didnt already believe based off of the rest of the proof here)

Comment: @HorusKol Nice catch; I have no doubt that there are tons more examples, but that's a quite significant one so I'll add it

Comment: I'll say Worf and K'Ehleyr had no problem concieving Alexander, since they weren't trying to have a child. The same on VOY with Tom and B'Elanna concieving Miral.

Answer (score 5):

In the Star Trek novel "[Yesterday's Son](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yesterday's_Son)", it's revealed that Spock and [Zarabeth](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Zarabeth) (seen in the TOS episode [All Our Yesterdays](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/All_Our_Yesterdays_(episode))) had a child named Zar.

From the blurb:

> "The starship Enterprise must protect the Guardian – or destroy it.
>   But Spock has already used the portal to journey to the past. On the
>   planet Sarpeidon, 5,000 years ago, Spock knew a beautiful, primitive
>   woman. **Now he has gone back to meet his son!**"

The cover even sports a picture of the boy in question:

[image]

Comment: Apparently that hair style is genetic - who knew.

Comment: @Bachrach44 - lol, actually in the novel once they meet Zar styles his hair after his father's on purpose. He tries to emulate the Vulcan but is ultimately too emotional.

Comment: @Omegacron fascinating.